# Rally Cumulative Flow Diagram with Points

Tags: rally

I'm looking to try and do a cumulative flow diagram by story points in rally with their newer API/SDK and found some sample code on their GitHub page [RallyAnalytics GitHub](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/RallyAnalytics/tree/master/deploy)

So after some work I have it working to some degree but don't understand or can find any documentation for how to configure this more. It looks like the report being generated is doing count and not the PlanEstimate which I tried to add in fieldsToSum. How can I get it to sum the PlanEstimate field by c_KanbanState and not just give me a count of stories that matched the c_KanbanState for that week?  Sample code below minus the minified code from GitHub.

```
     var userConfig = {
            title: 'Cumulative Flow Diagram',
            debug: false,
            trace: false,
            // asOf: "2012-11-01",  // Optional. Only supply if want a specific time frame. Do not send in new Date().toISOString().
            granularity: 'week',
            fieldsToSum: ['PlanEstimate'],
            scopeField: "Project",  // Supports Iteration, Release, Tags, Project, _ProjectHierarchy, _ItemHierarchy
            scopeValue: 'scope',
            scopeData: {
              StartDate: new Date("2012-12-01T07:00:00.000Z"),
              EndDate: new Date(new Date()),
              Name: ""
            },
            //fieldNames: ['count', 'PlanEstimate']

            kanbanStateField: 'c_KanbanState',
            chartSeries: [
              {name: 'To Do'},
              {name: 'Dev Ready'},
              {name: 'In Dev'},
              {name: 'Peer Review'},
              {name: 'QA Ready'},
              {name: 'QA Done'},
              {name: 'Accepted'}
            ]
        }
         (function() {

            var charts = {};
            var visualizer;
            var nameToDisplayNameMap;

            createVisualization = function(visualizationData) {

              if (typeof visualizationData !== "undefined" && visualizationData !== null) {
                categories = visualizationData.categories;
                series = visualizationData.series;
                charts.lowestValueInLastState = visualizationData.lowestValueInLastState;

                charts.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                  chart: {
                     renderTo: 'chart-container',
                     defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                     zoomType: 'x'
                  },
                  legend: {
                     enabled: true
                  },
                  credits: {
                     enabled: false
                  },
                  title: {
                     text: userConfig.title
                  },
                  subtitle: {
                     text: userConfig.scopeData.Name
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                     categories: categories,
                     tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                     tickInterval: Math.floor(categories.length / 12) + 1,
                     title: {
                         text: userConfig.granularity.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + userConfig.granularity.slice(1) + 's'
                     }
                  },
                  yAxis: [
                     {
                         title: {
                             text: 'Total Points',
                         },
                         min: charts.lowestValueInLastState
                     }                    
                  ],
                  tooltip: {
                     formatter: function() {
                         point = this.point
                         s = point.series.name + ': <b>' + point.y + '</b><br \>';
                         if (point.x == point.series.data.length - 1) {
                             s += point.category.slice(0, point.category.length - 1) + ' to-date';
                         } else {
                             s += point.category;
                         }
                         return s;
                     }
                  },
                  plotOptions: {
                      series: {
                          events: {
                              legendItemClick: function(event) {
                                  if (this.chart.series.length == this.index + 1) {
                                      if (!this.visible) {
                                         this.chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(charts.lowestValueInLastState);
                                      } else {
                                         this.chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0);
                                      };
                                  };
                                  return true;
                              }
                          }                          
                      }
                  },    

                  series: series
                });  // end of chart

              } else {
                // Put a spinner in the chart containers until first fetch returns
                $('#chart-container')
                  .html('<img height="20px" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/grid/loading.gif"></img>')
                  .attr("style", "text-align:center");

              };   

            };   


            $(document).ready(function() {
              visualizer = new CFDVisualizer(charts, userConfig, createVisualization);
            });

        })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using a slightly older version because the latest doesn't have the fieldsToSum parameter in the config, but you can upgrade the chart to sum PlanEstimate by chaging a few lines in the CFDVisualizer.coffee to this:

```
@config.lumenizeCalculatorConfig.metrics = [
  {f: 'groupBySum', field: 'PlanEstimate', groupByField: @config.kanbanStateField, allowedValues: allowedValues}
]
```

from:

```
@config.lumenizeCalculatorConfig.metrics = [
  {f: 'groupByCount', groupByField: @config.kanbanStateField, allowedValues: allowedValues}
]
```

You should probably also change the axis label in the cfd.html.

If this proves too difficult to accomplish (CoffeeScript may be unfamiliar), let me know and I'll post a new version to GitHub.

Comment: I was able to find the code in the deployed version after it was minified. Changing those lines made it work out just the way I needed it. Thanks!